# Flutter BLoC/Cubit STATE class best practices

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I'm new to using Bloc and Cubit so I'm trying to figure out some best practices specifically with the State component. I have a simple Todos app where the Todos can be in multiple different states:

```
part of 'todos_cubit.dart';

abstract class TodosState extends Equatable {
  const TodosState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class TodosLoading extends TodosState {}

class TodosLoaded extends TodosState {
  final List<Todo> todos;

  TodosLoaded(this.todos);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is TodosLoaded && listEquals(other.todos, todos);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => todos.hashCode;
}

class TodosEmpty extends TodosState {}

class TodosError extends TodosState {
  final String error;

  TodosError(this.error);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is TodosError && other.error == error;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => error.hashCode;
}
```

My question is, should I keep the `List<Todo> todos` in the `TodosLoaded` subclass or should it be moved to the base class? My thoughts are that by moving it to the base class, it would make my `TodosEmpty` state redundant because I could simple check to see if the list of todos is empty in the UI. If this is the case, should I also move the `String error` to the base class?

Im sure there are pros and cons to each approach, just hoping to bounce ideas off anyone with more experience with Bloc.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Cubit, it simplifies the code a lot.

I would probably create a function `addToDo(todoItem)` and `removeToDo(todoItem)` in the cubit class that updates the list and emits the change. The list variable would be in the Cubit, and you will refer to this list from the Widget by using `context.read<TodoCubit>().todoList`.

And you will use the functions like so: `context.read<TodoCubit>().addToDo(todoItem)`

I've written a tutorial for best approach for Cubit implementation *[Flutter | Firebase Authentication with Cubit (Bloc) — Tutorial 1 of 2](https://flutter-developer.medium.com/flutter-firebase-authentication-with-cubit-bloc-tutorial-1-of-2-3e44de433cf2)*

I think this article will be a lot of help for you. Take a look

Comment: I am using Cubit already. I was just wondering about best practices when designing each of my states and whether the list of todos should be in TodosState or TodosLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

For somebody checking this thread, having states like `TodosEmpty` and `TodosLoaded` with the list of todos is very much OK. Although, I would go with  [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package and simplify it, like I did in with my app:

part of 'books_list_cubit.dart';

```
@freezed
class BooksListPageState with _$BooksListPageState {
  const factory BooksListPageState.loading() = BooksListPageLoading;

  const factory BooksListPageState.empty() = BooksListPageEmpty;

  const factory BooksListPageState.success(List<Book> books) = BooksListPageSuccess;
}
```

More on this is in my [Flutter cubits + hooks + Hive DB](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/flutter-list-details-app-with-cubits-hooks-and-hive-database-2e87be09b580) tutorial.